# Why don't electrons pair up in an oxygen radical?

Tags: electronic-configuration, radicals

In an oxygen radical (produced by the break down of O3 for instance), there are 2 unpaired electrons in the outermost subshell which make the molecule unstable. Why don't these electrons pair up which would make the atom more stable (I think)?

Answer (score 1):

Pairing up of electrons in this case is unfavourable due to increased inter-electron repulsion; the average spatial separation of the electrons is higher in the triplet state where the two electrons are unpaired. Regular oxygen molecules also exist in a triplet state and have unpaired valence electrons; they are said to be biradicals.